# How to search and retrieve records using c++

Tags: c++

I'm making a simple console system project for college using C++. The purpose of the system is to add, search and retrieve data. It seems to be working for the most part but the searching part of the system isn’t working properly. It gets the data with no problem; however, when we get to the display part, the data is scrambled all over the place. On the other side, when I just go to retrieve some data without searching for it first, it's displayed properly on the console.

I think there's a problem with my search (function).

Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

struct person
{
    char Name[20], id[10], gender[7];
};

class MANAGER
{
public:
    person manager;
    char salary[7], department[20];

    MANAGER() {
        cout << "the managers file has opened... \n";
    }

    void add() {
        fstream MAN_file;
        MAN_file.open("Managers_Records.txt", ios::app | ios::binary);
        if (MAN_file.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Enter Manager full name: "; cin.getline(manager.Name, 20);
            cout << "Enter Manager ID: "; cin.getline(manager.id, 10);
            cout << "Enter Manager Gender(male/female): "; cin.getline(manager.gender, 7);
            cout << "Enter Manager salary: "; cin.getline(salary, 7);
            cout << "Enter the Manager's department: "; cin.getline(department, 20);
            cout << "_____________________________\n";

            MAN_file.write(manager.Name, strlen(manager.Name)); MAN_file.put('-');
            MAN_file.write(manager.id, strlen(manager.id)); MAN_file.put('-');
            MAN_file.write(manager.gender, strlen(manager.gender)); MAN_file.put('-');
            MAN_file.write(salary, strlen(salary)); MAN_file.put('-');
            MAN_file.write(department, strlen(department)); MAN_file.put('|');
            MAN_file.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error";
        }
    }
    void read() {
        ifstream MAN_file;
        MAN_file.open("Managers_Records.txt", ios::binary);
        if (MAN_file.is_open())
        {
            char M_n[20], M_i[10], M_g[7], M_s[7], M_dep[20];
            while (!MAN_file.eof())
            {

                MAN_file.getline(M_n, 20, '-');
                MAN_file.getline(M_i, 10, '-');
                MAN_file.getline(M_g, 7, '-');
                MAN_file.getline(M_s, 7, '-');
                MAN_file.getline(M_dep, 20, '|');

                cout << "Manager name is: " << M_n << " \n";
                cout << "Manager ID is: " << M_i << " \n";
                cout << "Manager Gender is: " << M_g << " \n";
                cout << "Manager salary is: " << M_s << " \n";
                cout << "Manager's department is: " << M_dep << " \n";
                cout << "________________________________" << endl;
            }
            MAN_file.close();
        }
    }
    //void delet() {}

    void search() {
        char M_n[20], M_i[10], M_g[7], M_s[7], M_dep[20];
        char Temp[500];
        int Position;
        ifstream MAN_file;
        MAN_file.open("Managers_Records.txt", ios::binary);

        if(MAN_file.is_open()){
            cout << "Type the ID of the record you want to search for: ";
            cin.getline(manager.id, 10);

            while(-1){
                MAN_file.getline(Temp, 100, '-');
                for(int i = 0;Temp[i] == manager.id[i]; i++){
                    if(MAN_file.eof()){
                        cout << "No Match!! \n";
                        break;}
                    if(manager.id[i] == '\0'){
                        Position = MAN_file.tellg();
                        cout << "The ID Position is: " << Position << "\n";
                        MAN_file.getline(M_n, 20, '-');
                        MAN_file.getline(M_i, 10, '-');
                        MAN_file.getline(M_g, 7, '-');
                        MAN_file.getline(M_s, 7, '-');
                        MAN_file.getline(M_dep, 20, '|');

                        cout << "Manager name is: " << M_n << " \n";
                        cout << "Manager ID is: " << M_i << " \n";
                        cout << "Manager Gender is: " << M_g << " \n";
                        cout << "Manager salary is: " << M_s << " \n";
                        cout << "Manager's department is: " << M_dep << " \n";
                        cout << "________________________________" << endl;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ~MANAGER() {
        cout << "the managers file has been closed...";
    }

};

class ASSISTANT
{
public:
    person assistant;
    char salay[7], specialization[20] ;

    ASSISTANT() {
        cout << "the assistants file has opened...";
    }

    void add() {
        fstream ASSIST_file;
        ASSIST_file.open("Assistants_Records.txt", ios::app | ios::binary);
        if (ASSIST_file.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Enter assistant full name: "; cin.getline(assistant.Name, 20);
            cout << "Enter assistant ID: "; cin.getline(assistant.id, 10);
            cout << "Enter assistant Gender(male/female): "; cin.getline(assistant.gender, 7);
            cout << "Enter assistant specialization: "; cin.getline(specialization, 20);
            cout << "Enter assistant salary: "; cin.getline(salay, 7);
            cout << "_____________________________\n";

            ASSIST_file.write(assistant.Name, strlen(assistant.Name)); ASSIST_file.put('-');
            ASSIST_file.write(assistant.id, strlen(assistant.id)); ASSIST_file.put('-');
            ASSIST_file.write(assistant.gender, strlen(assistant.gender)); ASSIST_file.put('-');
            ASSIST_file.write(specialization, strlen(specialization)); ASSIST_file.put('-');
            ASSIST_file.write(salay, strlen(salay)); ASSIST_file.put('|');
            ASSIST_file.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error";
        }
    }
    void read() {
        ifstream ASSIST_file;
        ASSIST_file.open("Assistants_Records.txt", ios::binary);
        if (ASSIST_file.is_open())
        {
            char A_n[20], A_i[10], A_g[7], A_spec[20], A_s[7];
            while (!ASSIST_file.eof())
            {

                ASSIST_file.getline(A_n, 20, '-');
                ASSIST_file.getline(A_i, 10, '-');
                ASSIST_file.getline(A_g, 7, '-');
                ASSIST_file.getline(A_spec, 20, '-');
                ASSIST_file.getline(A_s, 20, '|');

                cout << "Assistant name is: " << A_n << " \n";
                cout << "Assistant ID is: " << A_i << " \n";
                cout << "Assistant Gender is: " << A_g << " \n";
                cout << "Assistant Specialization is: " << A_spec << "\n";
                cout << "Assistant's salary is: " << A_s << " \n";
            }
            ASSIST_file.close();

        }


    }
    void delet() {



    }
    void search() {
        char A_n[20], A_i[10], A_g[7], A_spec[20], A_s[7];      
        char Temp[500];
        int Position;
        ifstream ASSIST_file;
        ASSIST_file.open("Assistants_Records.txt", ios::binary);

        if(ASSIST_file.is_open()){
            cout << "Type the ID of the record you want to search for: ";
            cin.getline(assistant.id, 10);

            while(-1){
                ASSIST_file.getline(Temp, 100, '-');
                for(int i = 0;Temp[i] == assistant.id[i]; i++){
                    if(ASSIST_file.eof()){
                        cout << "No Match!! \n";
                        break;}
                    if(assistant.id[i] == '\0'){
                        Position = ASSIST_file.tellg();
                        cout << "The ID Position is: " << Position << "\n";
                        ASSIST_file.getline(A_n, 20, '-');
                        ASSIST_file.getline(A_i, 10, '-');
                        ASSIST_file.getline(A_g, 7, '-');
                        ASSIST_file.getline(A_spec, 20, '-');
                        ASSIST_file.getline(A_s, 20, '|');

                        cout << "Assistant name is: " << A_n << " \n";
                        cout << "Assistant ID is: " << A_i << " \n";
                        cout << "Assistant Gender is: " << A_g << " \n";
                        cout << "Assistant Specialization is: " << A_spec << "\n";
                        cout << "Assistant's salary is: " << A_s << " \n";  

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ~ASSISTANT() {
        cout << "the assistants file has been closed...";
    }

};

class PATIENT
{
public:
    person patient;
    char age[5], diag[20], doc[20];

    PATIENT() {
        cout << "the patients file has opened...";
    }

    void add() {
        fstream PAT_file;
        PAT_file.open("Patients_Records.txt", ios::app | ios::binary);
        if (PAT_file.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Enter patient full name: "; cin.getline(patient.Name, 20);
            cout << "Enter patient ID: "; cin.getline(patient.id, 10);
            cout << "Enter patient Gender(male/female): "; cin.getline(patient.gender, 7);
            cout << "Enter patient age: "; cin.getline(age, 5);
            cout << "Enter the Responsible Doctor's name: "; cin.getline(doc, 20);
            cout << "Enter the patient's diagnosis: "; cin.getline(diag, 20);
            cout << "_____________________________\n";

            PAT_file.write(patient.Name, strlen(patient.Name)); PAT_file.put('-');
            PAT_file.write(patient.id, strlen(patient.id)); PAT_file.put('-');
            PAT_file.write(patient.gender, strlen(patient.gender)); PAT_file.put('-');
            PAT_file.write(age, strlen(age)); PAT_file.put('-');
            PAT_file.write(doc, strlen(doc)); PAT_file.put('-');
            PAT_file.write(diag, strlen(diag)); PAT_file.put('|');
            PAT_file.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error";
        }
    }
    void raed() {
        ifstream PAT_file;
        PAT_file.open("Patients_Records.txt", ios::binary);
        if (PAT_file.is_open())
        {
            char P_n[20], P_i[10], P_g[7], P_a[5], P_d[20], P_dia[20];
            while (!PAT_file.eof())
            {

                PAT_file.getline(P_n, 20, '-');
                PAT_file.getline(P_i, 10, '-');
                PAT_file.getline(P_g, 7, '-');
                PAT_file.getline(P_a, 5, '-');
                PAT_file.getline(P_d, 20, '-');
                PAT_file.getline(P_dia, 20, '|');

                cout << "patient name is: " << P_n << " \n";
                cout << "patient ID is: " << P_i << " \n";
                cout << "patient Gender is: " << P_g << " \n";
                cout << "patient age is: " << P_a << " \n";
                cout << "the Responsible Doctor is: " << P_d << " \n";
                cout << "patient's diagnosis is: " << P_dia << " \n";
            }
            PAT_file.close();

        }

    }
    void delet() {

    }
    void search() {
        char P_n[20], P_i[10], P_g[7], P_a[5], P_d[20], P_dia[20];
        char Temp[500];
        int Position;
        ifstream PAT_file;
        PAT_file.open("Patients_Records.txt", ios::binary);

        if(PAT_file.is_open()){
            cout << "Type the ID of the record you want to search for: ";
            cin.getline(patient.id, 10);

            while(-1){
                PAT_file.getline(Temp, 100, '-');
                for(int i = 0;Temp[i] == patient.id[i]; i++){
                    if(PAT_file.eof()){
                        cout << "No Match!! \n";
                        break;}
                    if(patient.id[i] == '\0'){
                        Position = PAT_file.tellg();
                        cout << "The ID Position is: " << Position << "\n";
                        PAT_file.getline(P_n, 20, '-');
                        PAT_file.getline(P_i, 10, '-');
                        PAT_file.getline(P_g, 7, '-');
                        PAT_file.getline(P_a, 5, '-');
                        PAT_file.getline(P_d, 20, '-');
                        PAT_file.getline(P_dia, 20, '|');

                        cout << "patient name is: " << P_n << " \n";
                        cout << "patient ID is: " << P_i << " \n";
                        cout << "patient Gender is: " << P_g << " \n";
                        cout << "patient age is: " << P_a << " \n";
                        cout << "the Responsible Doctor is: " << P_d << " \n";
                        cout << "patient's diagnosis is: " << P_dia << " \n";

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ~PATIENT()
    {
        cout << "the patient file has been closed...";
    }
};

class DOCTOR
{
public:
    person doctor;
    char specialization[20], salary[7];

    DOCTOR() {
        cout << "the doctors file has opened...";
    }
    void add() {
        fstream DOC_file;
        DOC_file.open("Doctors_Records.txt", ios::app | ios::binary);
        if (DOC_file.is_open())
        {
            cout << "Enter doctor full name: "; cin.getline(doctor.Name, 20);
            cout << "Enter doctor ID: "; cin.getline(doctor.id, 10);
            cout << "Enter doctor Gender(male/female): "; cin.getline(doctor.gender, 7);
            cout << "Enter doctor salary: "; cin.getline(salary, 7);
            cout << "Enter doctor specialization: "; cin.getline(specialization, 20);
            cout << "_____________________________\n";

            DOC_file.write(doctor.Name, strlen(doctor.Name)); DOC_file.put('-');
            DOC_file.write(doctor.id, strlen(doctor.id)); DOC_file.put('-');
            DOC_file.write(doctor.gender, strlen(doctor.gender)); DOC_file.put('-');
            DOC_file.write(salary, strlen(salary)); DOC_file.put('-');
            DOC_file.write(specialization, strlen(specialization)); DOC_file.put('|');
            DOC_file.close();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Error";
        }
    }
    void raed() {
        ifstream DOC_file;
        DOC_file.open("Doctors_Records.txt", ios::binary);
        if (DOC_file.is_open())
        {
            char D_n[20], D_i[10], D_g[7], D_s[7], D_spec[20];
            while (!DOC_file.eof())
            {

                DOC_file.getline(D_n, 20, '-');
                DOC_file.getline(D_i, 10, '-');
                DOC_file.getline(D_g, 7, '-');
                DOC_file.getline(D_s, 7, '-');
                DOC_file.getline(D_spec, 20, '|');

                cout << "Doctor name is: " << D_n << " \n";
                cout << "Doctor ID is: " << D_i << " \n";
                cout << "Doctor Gender is: " << D_g << " \n";
                cout << "Doctor salary is: " << D_s << " \n";
                cout << "Doctor specialization is: " << D_spec << " \n";
            }
            DOC_file.close();

        }

    }
    void delet() {



    }
    void search() {
        char D_n[20], D_i[10], D_g[7], D_s[7], D_spec[20];
        char Temp[500];
        int Position;
        ifstream DOC_file;
        DOC_file.open("Doctors_Records.txt", ios::binary);

        if(DOC_file.is_open()){
            cout << "Type the ID of the record you want to search for: ";
            cin.getline(doctor.id, 10);

            while(-1){
                DOC_file.getline(Temp, 100, '-');
                for(int i = 0;Temp[i] == doctor.id[i]; i++){
                    if(DOC_file.eof()){
                        cout << "No Match!! \n";
                        break;}
                    if(doctor.id[i] == '\0'){
                        Position = DOC_file.tellg();
                        cout << "The ID Position is: " << Position << "\n";
                        DOC_file.getline(D_n, 20, '-');
                        DOC_file.getline(D_i, 10, '-');
                        DOC_file.getline(D_g, 7, '-');
                        DOC_file.getline(D_s, 7, '-');
                        DOC_file.getline(D_spec, 20, '|');

                        cout << "Doctor name is: " << D_n << " \n";
                        cout << "Doctor ID is: " << D_i << " \n";
                        cout << "Doctor Gender is: " << D_g << " \n";
                        cout << "Doctor salary is: " << D_s << " \n";
                        cout << "Doctor specialization is: " << D_spec << " \n";

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ~DOCTOR()
    {
        cout << "the doctor file has been closed...";
    }
};

int main()
{

    DOCTOR d;
    d.add();
    d.raed();
    d.search();

    PATIENT p;
    p.add();
    p.raed();
    p.search();

    MANAGER m;
    m.add();
    m.read();
    m.search();

    ASSISTANT a;
    a.add();
    a.read();
    a.search();
}
```

Comment: FYI, in common coding guidelines, names in ALLCAPS are reserved for macros.

Comment: Prefer to use `std::string` instead of character arrays.  Character arrays can overflow and are never big enough, except when they are.

Comment: Usually, a Patient is one, single, person.  A *database* contains information about zero **or more** Patients.  In other words, a patient doesn't search for other patients nor does a patient contain more patients.  Move the containers outside the single objects or classes.

Comment: Your constructor fo PATIENT lies.  There is no code to open files in the constructor.

Comment: For `class DOCTOR`, is the doctor a person (inheritance) or does the doctor contain a person (member/containment)?

Comment: Lastly, when you used the debugger, which statement(s) is causing the issue?  What are the actual outputs vs. the expected outputs?

Comment: The expected output is whatever data you search for displayed on the console the same way it’s in the actual record                                      For example                            The data in the record is like name: will Smith , id:23, address:23rd street queens, etc...                 the actual output displays the data in the record but it’s all scrambled                               Ex:                               name: 23 , id:23rd street queens, address: will Smith , etc...

Comment: Your file pointer is already forwarded when you did ```DOC_file.getline(Temp, 100, '-'); ```. So doing ```DOC_file.getline(D_n, 20, '-'); ``` won't give you the name.

Comment: You can get the current position using ```tellg()``` and restore it using ```seekg()```. Or come up with a better design- like reading the whole record till you find '|' and then parsing it.